# Python: UDP Proxy Multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, udp

I just can't manage to add Multithreading to my UDP Server.
A second client can connect, but instantly gets thrown out of the server when someone is already connected to it.

Could this be caused by something other than SingleThreading?

```
import sys, socket
localPort, remoteHost, remotePort = sys.argv[1].split(':')
try:
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(('', localPort))
except:
    fail('Failed to bind on port ' + str(localPort))

knownClient = None
knownServer = (remoteHost, remotePort)
sys.stderr.write('Ready.\n')


while True:
    data, addr = s.recvfrom(32768)
    print addr
    if knownClient is None:
        knownClient = addr
    if addr == knownClient:
        try:
            s.sendto(data, knownServer)
        except:
            pass
    else:
        try:
            s.sendto(data, knownClient)
        except:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write an UDP proxy with only port. How should you know from the answer of the server to which of the two connected clients you should send your answer. You have to open for each client a new socket to the remote server.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm new to Python. Could you please give me an example how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It's not Python but "networking" and for sure not "multithreading". You need to either direct the clients to different ports or create a new outgoing socket for each new client connection.

Because you have multiple sockets a very effective approach is to sit on `select` and wait for the incoming calls.

In order to identify the clients, it is also needed to keep a reference of the local addresses the new sockets are using to talk to the server.

Your code reworked to open a `socket` on each new incoming client connection. No guarantees, because that would involve network testing against an scenario (yours) which is unknown.

For a very robust implementation you would have to add error checking, socket removal for gone connections ...

```
import select
import socket
import sys


localPort, remoteHost, remotePort = sys.argv[1].split(':')

try:
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    server.bind(('', localPort))
except:
    fail('Failed to bind on port ' + str(localPort))

localaddr = s.getsockname()  # (localhost, localport)
remaddr = (remoteHost, remotePort)

sys.stderr.write('Ready.\n')

allsockets = [server]

proxysocks = dict()
origins = dict()


while True:
    toread, _, _ = select.select(allsockets, [], [])

    s = toread[0]  # 1st socket available to read
    data, orig = s.recvfrom(32768)  # data, (remhost,remport)
    dest = s.getsockname()  # (localhost, localport)

    if dst == localaddr:  # client -> localserver
        try:
            p = proxysocks[orig]  # find proxy sock
        except KeyError:  # new client connection
            proxysocks[orig] = p = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,
                                                 socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

            proxyaddr = p.getsockname()  # keep local address of new socket
            origins[proxyaddr] = orig  # link proxyaddr -> clientaddr

            allsockets.append(p)  # make it "selectable"

        p.sendto(remaddr, data)  # send to server

    else:  # server -> proxyaddr
        s.sendto(origins[dstaddr])
```